# Mysql query to display sum of column is row format

Tags: mysql

My input

```
Name     English    Maths     Social    
Mary        34       56         34    
Julie       23       45         67    
Maxy        34       62         54    
Sam         45       78         45
```

MY expected  output :

```
English      136       
Maths        241     
Social       200
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Further, consider revising your schema. A normalised design might have three columns, e.g.: name, subject, score

Answer (score -1):

In your case you simple use SUM() aggregate function
For further reference follow the link
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

SELECT SUM(english) AS English, SUM(math) AS Math, SUM(social) AS Social FROM your_table_name